# How to transfer contacts to Android?

Tags: contacts, android

How do I transfer contact from a Windows phone to an Android phone?

I just bought an Android phone for private use while keeping my Windows phone as a work phone. How do I transfer my contacts to my Android?

Comment: This might be more of a question for http://android.stackexchange.com/ As I would *expect* Android to be able to connect to the same Microsoft/Gmail accounts, etc. that you have used for storing your contacts on your windows phone

Comment: Maybe, but (just debating) keeping it here could give the question more Windows Phone perspective. How about rephrasing it as syncing contacts between the two OS's? @RowlandShaw

Comment: The background for the question is that syncing contacts with the Outlook app for Android was strange. Took maybe 48h before the sync started (or for me to find the option to enable it...).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick thought:

- Sync contacts from Windows phone to Microsoft account
- Export contacts from Microsoft account to computer
- Import contacts from computer to Gmail account
- Sync Gmail contacts to Android.

Or follow this [article](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/16450/how-to-transfer-contacts-to-android), there will be the other choices.

Comment: Can you not sync a Microsoft account with an Android device?

Comment: Ofcourse you can

Comment: So why bother with these steps?

Answer (score 0):

The contacts on your Windows Phone in the People app and outlook are synced to https://people.live.com.
So if you log in with your microsoft account to this website you can just export and backup your contacts there.

The steps are also described here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdtips/how-to-export-contacts-from-windows-phone-to-pc/e6f8292c-8081-45d6-a40d-7ff2337b8a41?auth=1

Update:

Another method:

1. add Microsoft Outlook app to android
2. add your Hotmail/outlook account
3. open the outlook app
4. click on the gear on the upper right corner in the outlook app
5. click on your account emailaddress under "Accounts"
6. Enable: "sync contacts" (dutch: "Contactpersonen synchroniseren")

Now you have your contacts app.

Now go to Contacts app, Settings, default account for new contacts, and select your outlook/Hotmail account ;-)